# Program runs without crashing but the answers are 0 no matter what the person puts as a variable

Tags: c++, variables, output

Ok so this runs, but it doesn't do the calculations.
when the window comes up I type in A B or C and then the length of the words
and it just says pay=0. Also Ive tried a few different ways but I cant figure out how to get it to reset for the person to put in new author level and number of words

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>




using namespace std;


char authorLevel;
int numberOfWords, payTotal;
int fixedPayAmount;



int main()
{


cout << "Enter Author Level(A,B,or C):";
char authorLevel;
cin >>authorLevel;

cout << "Enter Length(in words):";
int numberOfWords;
cin >>numberOfWords;

cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl; 
int payTotal;


cout << "Fixed Pay is:$" << fixedPayAmount << endl;
int fixedPayAmount;

//Calculations for C Level Author


if (authorLevel == 'C')
{

         //If the Number of words is <7500 multiply by 0.08     
              if (numberOfWords <=7500)
                  {
                    payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.08;                     
                  }

        //If the numberOfWords is >7500 to <=8000 pay is fixed 600
                if (numberOfWords >7500 || numberOfWords <= 8000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount= 600;

                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >8000 to <=17500 multiply by 0.075
              if (numberOfWords >8000 || numberOfWords <=17500)     
                    {
                    payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.075;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >17500 to <= 19000 fixed $1313
             if (numberOfWords >17500 || numberOfWords <= 19000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount=1313;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >=19000 multiply 0.07
            if (numberOfWords >=19000)
            {
                payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.07;
            }
}

else if (authorLevel== 'A')
    {


         //If the Number of words is <7500 multiply by 0.14     
              if (numberOfWords <=7500)
                  {
                    payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.14;
                    }

        //If the numberOfWords is >7500 to <=8000 pay is fixed $1050
                if (numberOfWords >7500 || numberOfWords <= 8000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount= 1050;

                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >8000 to <=17500 multiply by 0.13125
              if (numberOfWords >8000 || numberOfWords <=17500)     
                    {                                               
                    payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.13125;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >17500 to <= 19000 fixed $2297.75
             if (numberOfWords >17500 || numberOfWords <= 19000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount=2297.75;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >=19000 multiply 0.1225
            if (numberOfWords >=19000)
            {
                payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.1225;
            }
    }



    else if (authorLevel== 'B')
    {

         //If the Number of words is <7500 multiply by 0.1  
              if (numberOfWords <=7500)
                  {
                        payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.1;
                    }

        //If the numberOfWords is >7500 to <=8000 pay is fixed $750
                if (numberOfWords >7500 || numberOfWords <= 8000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount= 750;

                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >8000 to <=17500 multiply by 0.09375
              if (numberOfWords >8000 || numberOfWords <=17500)     
                    {
                    payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.09375;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >17500 to <= 19000 fixed $1641.25
             if (numberOfWords >17500 || numberOfWords <= 19000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount=1641.25;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >=19000 multiply 0.0875
            if (numberOfWords >=19000)
            {
                payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.0875;
            }
    }


            return 0;
}
```

its stuck on the first fixed pay of each as the output now,itll do the first part <=7500 but any number above itll set the answer to be the first fixedPay. I editied my question above to show the new code

Here is new code:

```
#include <iostream>




using namespace std;


float authorLevel;
float numberOfWords, payTotal;
float fixedPayAmount;



int main()
{



cout << "Enter Author Level(A,B, or C):";
char authorLevel;
cin >>authorLevel;

cout << "Enter Length(in words):";
int numberOfWords;
cin >>numberOfWords;






//Calculations for C Level Author


if (authorLevel == 'C')
{

         //If the Number of words is <7500 multiply by 0.08     
              if (numberOfWords <=7500)
                  {
                        payTotal= (numberOfWords * 0.08);
                        cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl; 


                  }

        //If the numberOfWords is >7500 to <=8000 pay is fixed 600
                else if (numberOfWords >7500 || numberOfWords <= 8000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount= 600;
                    cout << "Fixed Pay is:$" << fixedPayAmount << endl;

                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >8000 to <=17500 multiply by 0.075
              else if (numberOfWords >8000 || numberOfWords <=17500)        
                    {
                        payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.075;
                        cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >17500 to < 19000 fixed $1313
             else if (numberOfWords >17500 || numberOfWords < 19000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount=1313;
                    cout << "Fixed Pay is:$" << fixedPayAmount << endl;

                        }
        //If the numberOfWords is >=19000 multiply 0.07
        else if (numberOfWords >=19000)
            {
                payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.07;
                    cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl;
            }

}

else if (authorLevel== 'A')
    {


         //If the Number of words is <7500 multiply by 0.14     
             if (numberOfWords <=7500)
                  {
                        payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.14;
                        cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl;
                    }

        //If the numberOfWords is >7500 to <=8000 pay is fixed $1050
            else if (numberOfWords >7500 || numberOfWords < 8000)
                    {
                    fixedPayAmount= 1050;
                    cout << "Fixed Pay is:$" << fixedPayAmount << endl;                     
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >8000 to <=17500 multiply by 0.13125
              else if (numberOfWords >=8000 || numberOfWords <=17500)       
                    {                                               
                        payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.13125;
                        cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >17500 to <= 19000 fixed $2297.75
             else if (numberOfWords >17500 || numberOfWords <19000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount=2297.75;
                    cout << "Fixed Pay is:$" << fixedPayAmount << endl;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >=19000 multiply 0.1225
            else if (numberOfWords >=19000)
            {
                payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.1225;
                    cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl;
            }
    }



    else if (authorLevel== 'B')
    {

         //If the Number of words is <7500 multiply by 0.1  
              if (numberOfWords <=7500)
                  {
                        payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.1;
                        cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl;
                    }

        //If the numberOfWords is >7500 to <=8000 pay is fixed $750
                else if (numberOfWords >7500 || numberOfWords <= 8000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount= 750;
                    cout << "Fixed Pay is:$" << fixedPayAmount << endl;                     
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >8000 to <=17500 multiply by 0.09375
              else if (numberOfWords >8000 || numberOfWords <=17500)        
                    {
                        payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.09375;
                        cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >17500 to <= 19000 fixed $1641.25
             else if (numberOfWords >17500 || numberOfWords < 19000)
                    {
                        fixedPayAmount=1641.25;
                    cout << "Fixed Pay is:$" << fixedPayAmount<< endl;
                    }
        //If the numberOfWords is >=19000 multiply 0.0875
            else if (numberOfWords >=19000)
            {
                payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.0875;
                cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl;
            }
    }

            return 0;

}
```

Comment: There are two `payTotal` variables in this code. You also print the `payTotal` before you even compute its value.

Comment: Also, as a former TA and grader, please indent your code properly.

Comment: You are also multiplying an int by a float and assigning the result back to an int, you should probably make payTotal a float. Otherwise, for smaller values of numberOfWords you will also get zero.

Comment: omgosh thank you soooooooo much! It seems kinda obvious to me now but ive been having trouble with it all day.

Comment: temporal awareness. It is due to a lack of

Comment: its stuck on the first fixed pay of each as the output now,itll do the first part <=7500 but any number above itll set the answer to be the first fixedPay. I editied my question above to show the new code

Comment: If your having problems with home work you should really talk to your instructor. You are paying them to teach you, and hiding the fact that struggling will only leave you off of their radar.  If you want the most from your education then go to them during their office hours and let them know where you stand.  Its how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out the value before you compute it.
    int payTotal;

```
....
cout << "Pay is: $" << payTotal << endl; 
int payTotal;

// code to actually compute the value of payTotal.
```

Note also that you have a global and a local payTotal. In this case that doesn't matter, but when you write more complex codes this can really come to bite you.

As @Andrew points out, there is another problem with int/float conversions. This code:

```
          if (numberOfWords <=7500)
              {
                payTotal= numberOfWords * 0.08;                     
              }
```

will set `payTotal` to `0` if `numberOfWords` is less than 13. The reason is nuanced, so a good rule of thunb is that if you're dealing with floats then make every variable in the calculation a float.

Comment: its stuck on the first fixed pay of each as the output now,itll do the first part <=7500 but any number above itll set the answer to be the first fixedPay. I editied my question above to show the new code

Answer (score -2):

it's because you have return 0; at the end and it should be return payTotal;